# Can't write SetContentView in newly created activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm new to android/xamarin development. I have created a new activity and now want to link this up with my view.

But I can't seem to write SetContentView (it doesn't exist).

Can't figure out what's going on here.

Thanks[image]

Comment: Tried "setC.." instead of "SetC.." ?
I don't know, not a Xamarin Dev.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it's not inheriting from Activity (based on color scheme). why' this?

Comment: @magna_nz Can you share lines 1-8 of your screen shot.

Answer (score 2):

`SetContentView` is in the namespace `Android.App`;

So add the following to your using clauses:

```
using Android.App;
```

And then you will be able to do something like:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
```

Ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.SetContentView/p/Android.Views.View/

Comment: Had he not inlcuded Android.App namespace, Activity too would not be available, no ?. @magna_nz Can you share full activity code ?

Comment: @Sreeraj Good point, I did not see that his screen shot started on line 9 and yes, the `Activity` that he should be sub-classing is in `Android.App`, We need to see entire code...